# Unable to get XML response from PHP page in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: php, ajax, html, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have a local apache 2.2 server on my pc. I am using PHP 5 and MySQL 5.0 on my system. I have created a table in my MySQL database called html5 that has one column and one row containing an arbitrary string.

I have created a PHP page called sample.php that connects to my MySQL db and extracts info of the above table and returns it as an XML file.

```
<?php   
    if(!$dbconnect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password')) {
       echo "Connection failed to the host 'localhost'.";
       exit;
    } // if
    if (!mysql_select_db('mysampledb')) {
       echo "Cannot connect to database 'mysampledb'";
       exit;
    } // if

    $table_id = 'html5';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table_id";
    $dbresult = mysql_query($query, $dbconnect);

    // create a new XML document
    $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');

    // create root node
    $root = $doc->createElement('note');
    $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

    // process one row at a time
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
    {
        // add node for each row
        $occ = $doc->createElement($table_id);
        $occ = $root->appendChild($occ);

        // add a child node for each field
        foreach ($row as $fieldname => $fieldvalue)
        {
            //create child element in xml file
            $child = $doc->createElement($fieldname);
            $child = $occ->appendChild($child);

            //add database content into the child element created above
            $value = $doc->createTextNode($fieldvalue);
            $value = $child->appendChild($value);

        }// foreach
    }// while

    // get completed xml document
    $xml_string = $doc->saveXML();
    echo $xml_string;
?>
```

I have created an HTML5 page *in a separate directory* that makes a simple request to the above PHP page with the click of a button and tries to grab the response and display it as an alert.

This is the HTML5 page: -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>          
        <button onclick="myFunc()">Click me</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunc()
            {               
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url:"http://localhost/sample.php"+"?randVar="+Math.random(),
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "text/xml",
                        success:function(result)
                        {
                            alert(result);
                        }
                    });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I run this page I get the response only in IE9. In Firefox and Chrome, I see **an empty alert**.

Prior to trying this way I had also tried using the XMLHttpRequest object but even that way I get response only on IE9.

```
function myFunc()
{
    var xmlhttp, xmlDoc;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    try
    {                   
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/sample.php"+"?randVar="+Math.random(),false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e.message);
    }               
    alert(xmlDoc);
}
```

In Firefox, the catch block returns "Failure" and in Chrome, the alert says **XMLHttpRequest Exception 101**.

P.S: -

1. Keeping the HTML file in the same htdocs folder as the sample.php page would solve the problem but it's not possible in the real world where the server is a separate computer on a different network. So I am not looking for this suggestion.
2. In the ajax call, making async="true" or "false" didn't make any difference.

This is the response in IE9: -
[image: Alert Message]

Firebug: -
[image: Firebug]

Could anyone please offer me a solution? I need one badly.

Comment: Can you post the response of the ajax request in console of firebug/chrome inspector?

Comment: Karan, I am getting response 200 OK.

Comment: Maybe take a look at Cross Origin Resource Sharing -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

Answer (score 1):

After quite some resource I found this solution:

Adding **header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');** in the PHP file is solving my problem beautifully.

Thanks everyone for your efforts!

Courtesy: [Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 0):

Place the following header in your php file:

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/xml, charset=utf-8' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the data type and try.

It supports only : `dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))`

```
$.ajax(
                {
                    url:"http://localhost/sample.php"+"?randVar="+Math.random(),
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success:function(result)
                    {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: just inspect in your firebug console you can see the response data there, even if it is not able to alert.

Comment: Prasanth, changing the datatype isn't showing any alert at all. And in IE9, it generates an error "Object doesn't support property or method".

Comment: In Firebug, response is 200 OK but either way it says XML parsing error.